# 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x, file

Getting the infamous `'str' object has no attribute 'write'`. Here I can't tell why python thinks my file object `out_file` is a string. Probably something else I'm missing. The error is flagged on the commented line.

PS this code is for printing a more reader friendly version of an arbitrary json.

```
import json
import os
json_path = os.path.normpath(r"my_dir")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
def json_break(data, tab_str, out_file):
    k_str = tab_str
    if type(data) is list:
        i = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            json_break(data[i], tab_str + '  ', str(data[i]))
            i += 1
    elif type(data) is dict:
        for k in data:
            if type(data[k]) is str:
                k_str += k + ': ' + data[k]
                out_file.write(k_str)
            else:
                k_str += k + ':\n'
                out_file.write(k_str)  # 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
                json_break(data[k], tab_str + ' ', out_file)
    return None
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

with open(os.path.join(json_path,'my_json.json')) as in_file:
    data = json.load(in_file)

out_file = open(os.path.join(json_path,'print_json.txt'),"w") 

tab_str = ' '
json_break(data, tab_str, out_file)

out_file.close()
```

Comment: `json_break(data[i], tab_str + '  ', str(data[i]))` <- `str(data[i])` doesn't look like a file object to me.

Comment: Nice spot. Simple as that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`json_break()` accepts last arg as a file object. Replace

```
json_break(data[i], tab_str + '  ', str(data[i]))
```

With

```
json_break(data[i], tab_str + '  ', out_file)
```

And it should work

Comment: Nope, the last arg is file object.

Comment: Yes, you suggested passing in `data[i]`, which is a list or dictionary into the the third arg of `json_break`. That arg should be a file object.

Comment: @Zduff changed.